# Connecting Windows to NAS - Samba server

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, samba, nas

I am trying to connect my Windows 7 to my NAS server (using Samba on Raspberry Pi, running with Arch Linux).

I've clicked on "Adding new network drive" -> \192.168.0.22\mnt\usb\Data 
which is the path to my external drive partition.
There is an authentification window, I'm typing the user and password that samba knows.

Then there is a a few seconds waiting time where Windows is computing/searching.
Finally I got a message which says that Windows can not reach \192.168.0.22\mnt\usb\Data

On my server:

```
ps aux |grep sm
root      1166  0.0  3.0  30464  5800 ?        Ss   11:16   0:00 /usr/bin/smbd -D
root      1167  0.0  1.6  29948  3056 ?        S    11:16   0:00 /usr/bin/smbd -D
arkon     1189  0.0  0.3   2336   648 pts/0    S+   11:20   0:00 grep sm
```

My configuration file is:

```
[global]
 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 server string = Samba Server
 netbios name = arkonberry
 security = user
 guest account = user
 force user = user 
 username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
 name resolve order = hosts wins bcast
 read only = no
 #wins support = no

[Data]
comment = Public Storage
path = /mnt/usb/Data
read only = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
```

Finally, my HDD is well mounted:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat     (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/usb/git type fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/usb/Download type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/usb/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Do you have any idea about where does the problem might come please ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that *should* be working. Mine looks as near identical to that set-up as can be.

The only 'problem' I see is that you're running Arch. Don't get me wrong, I love Arch, but it can be a fickle thing when using SMB, at least the first couple of times you set it up.

I used this [guide](http://obihoernchen.net/wordpress/877/setup-samba-4-on-arch-linux/) not long ago, and it works just fine.

The next hurdle I had was permissions. Make sure you check/repair the permissions for the drive or folder you're sharing.

Other than that, it could be a router issue, one of my old Belkins used to hate routing to my SUSE NAS.

Well, I'm sorry I can't be of more help, but I hope it gives you some places to start looking.

Comment: Okay thanks I've almost made it working. I rechecked everything using your guide. Here were my mistakes: the tag [public] is a reference to the directory. In this case, it should have been [Data].This is what I've used for the [Data] section: comment = Public Storage path = /mnt/usb/Data read only = no writable = yes browsable = yes . Finally, the path to add is \\server\directory and not \\server\path\to\directory.
I have some HDD issues now, I/O errors. But this problem is solved thank you !